# Caching with OkHttp (without Retrofit)

Tags: android, okhttp

In my Application onCreate, I'm creating a 10MB cache:

```
try
{
    File httpCacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), Constants.AppName);
    long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
    HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Log.i(Constants.AppName, "HTTP response cache installation failed: " + ex);
}
```

And my call to a resource:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setResponseCache(HttpResponseCache.getInstalled());

HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);
connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=60");
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

I'll initialize this call twice, within 10 seconds of one another, and the OkHttp-Response-Source header is always NETWORK 200.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> k : connection.getHeaderFields().entrySet())
{
    for (String v : k.getValue())
    {
        Log.d(Constants.AppName, k.getKey() + ": " + v);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OkHttp implement the [HTTP 1.1 RFC for HTTP cache](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). That means, for any URL your are trying to reach, the response needs to return at least the `Cache-Control` header:

> The basic cache mechanisms in HTTP/1.1 (server-specified expiration
>   times and validators) are implicit directives to caches. In some
>   cases, a server or client might need to provide explicit directives to
>   the HTTP caches. We use the Cache-Control header for this purpose.
>
> The Cache-Control header allows a client or server to transmit a
>   variety of directives in either requests or responses. These
>   directives typically override the default caching algorithms. As a
>   general rule, if there is any apparent conflict between header values,
>   the most restrictive interpretation is applied (that is, the one that
>   is most likely to preserve semantic transparency). However,
>
> in some cases, cache-control directives are explicitly specified as
>   weakening the approximation of semantic transparency (for example,
>   "max-stale" or "public").
>
> The cache-control directives are described in detail in section 14.9.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I looked and my source, and sure enough, it's not being returned. :-(

Comment: I struggled a lot to make it work too. Basically, all the job has to be done in the server configuration to return the correct set of headers. Once I realized that, it all went easier :)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I don't control the server.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As of OKHttp 2.2.0 you can use networkInterceptors() to add in a Cache-Control header to the response in cases were the API response header is configured incorrectly (or more likely just targeted for web)