# Retrofit - Okhttp client How to cache the response

Tags: java, android, retrofit, cache-control, okhttp

I'm trying to cache the response of http calls done by Retrofit(v 1.9.0) with OkHttp(2.3.0). It always made the network calls if I try to make a call without internet then `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

**RestClient**

```
public class RestClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://something.example.net/JSONService";
private com.ucc.application.rest.ApiService apiService;

public RestClient() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
            .create();

    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            int maxAge = 60 * 60;
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge);
        }
    };

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(OkHttpSingleTonClass.getOkHttpClient()))
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();

    apiService = restAdapter.create(com.ucc.application.rest.ApiService.class);
}

public com.ucc.application.rest.ApiService getApiService() {
    return apiService;
}

}
```

**OkHttpSingleTonClass**

```
public class OkHttpSingleTonClass {


private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

private OkHttpSingleTonClass() {
}

public static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    if (okHttpClient == null) {
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        createCacheForOkHTTP();
    }
    return okHttpClient;
}

private static void createCacheForOkHTTP() {
    Cache cache = null;
    cache = new Cache(getDirectory(), 1024 * 1024 * 10);
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
}

public static File getDirectory() {
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "UCC" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = UserUtil.CACHE_FILE_NAME;
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    return sdImageMainDirectory;
}

}
```

**MyActivity**

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .onlyIfCached()
                    .maxAge(60 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build())
            .url(RestClient.BASE_URL + Constants.GET_ABOUT_US_COLLECTION + "?userid=59e41b02-35ed-4962-8517-2668b5e8dae3&languageid=488d8f13-ef7d-4a3a-9516-0e0d24cbc720")
            .build();
    Log.d("url_request", RestClient.BASE_URL + Constants.GET_ABOUT_US_COLLECTION + "/?userid=10");
    com.squareup.okhttp.Response forceCacheResponse = null;
    try {
        forceCacheResponse = OkHttpSingleTonClass.getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (forceCacheResponse.code() != 504) {
        // The resource was cached! Show it.
        Log.d("From", "Local");
        Toast.makeText(AboutUs.this, "Local", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // The resource was not cached.
        Log.d("From", "Network");
        Toast.makeText(AboutUs.this, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getAbouUsDetails();//This will use the Apiservice interface to hit the server.

    }
```

I followed [this](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html). But I can't manage to work. Its simply hitting from the server. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you test http://stackoverflow.com/a/23503804/3824335 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22735632/3824335?

Comment: I had some issues with Pragma header and finally found a way to make it work with removing that header value. Here's a demo project that brings all the concepts together in anyone needs it. https://github.com/digitalbuddha/StoreDemo

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per Retrofit `1.9.0` which uses `OkClient` does not have Caching support. We have to use `OkHttpClient` instance by Square `OkHttpClient` library.

You can compile by `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'`

Before everything retrofit caches by response headers like

`Cache-Control:max-age=120,only-if-cached,max-stale`

** 120 is seconds.

You can read more about headers [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Caching headers are mostly instructed by server response. **Try to implement cache headers in servers.**  If you don't have an option, yes retrofit has it.

```
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", String.format("max-age=%d, only-if-cached, max-stale=%d", 120, 0))
                .build();
    }
};
```

**Where to cache:**

```
private static void createCacheForOkHTTP() {
    Cache cache = null;
    cache = new Cache(getDirectory(), 1024 * 1024 * 10);
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
}

// returns the file to store cached details
private File getDirectory() {
    return new File(“location”);
}
```

**Add interceptor to the OkHttpClient instance:**

```
okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);
```

**And finally add OkHttpClient to the RestAdapter:**

```
RestAdapter.setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));
```

And you can go through [this](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1eJa0gBZLpZRQ5vjW-eqLyekEgB54n4fQ1N4jDcgMZ1E/edit?usp=sharing) slide for more reference.