# How to show online data for offline without database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I want show 3 `fragments` in my `Activity` and load data from **`json`** in any `fragments`! I show websites data into `Recyclerview` with `OkHTTP v3` library. 
I want show this datas for offline, my mean is if user turn off data/wifi show this datas for **offline**. but i do not want use **SQLite Database**!
Can i use **`OkHTTP`** cache? 
 i don't know how to use `okhttp` cache.
**AsyncTask code:**

```
public class freeDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = freeServer_IP.getFreeIP();

    public void getFreeDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        //new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "limit=10");
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress);
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<DataModel> infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            //infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

            // Initiate Progress
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            this.dialog.setMessage("شکیبا باشید...");
            this.dialog.show();

            infoModels.clear();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    //.url(ServerAddress + "limit=10")
                    .url(ServerAddress)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("result");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);


                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String description = postObject.getString("full_description");
                            String image = postObject.getString("image");
                            String category = postObject.getString("categoryName");
                            String date = postObject.getString("date");
                            String url = postObject.getString("url");

                            Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + image);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post url: " + url);
                            Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new DataModel(id, title, description, category, date, url, image));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error2", String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();

            //Stop Progress
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(new MyEvent("forfragment1", infoModels));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "اتصال اینترنت خود را بررسی کنید", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class free_recycler_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<free_recycler_adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<DataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context context;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public free_recycler_adapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataSet) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public free_recycler_adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.free_card_layout, parent, false);

        // create ViewHolder
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // - get data from your itemsData at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that itemsData

        viewHolder.free_titleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_download_image)
                .crossFade()
                .into(viewHolder.free_avatarImage);

        viewHolder.free_descText.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDescription()));
        viewHolder.free_descText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ContentPage.class)
                        .putExtra("title", mDateSet.get(position).getTitle())
                        .putExtra("desc", mDateSet.get(position).getDescription())
                        .putExtra("image", mDateSet.get(position).getImage())
                        .putExtra("url", mDateSet.get(position).getUrl())
                        .putExtra("category", mDateSet.get(position).getCategory())
                        .putExtra("date", mDateSet.get(position).getDate()));
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(List<DataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<DataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView free_titleText, free_descText;
        public ImageView free_avatarImage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);

            free_titleText = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_title);
            free_descText = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_content);
            free_avatarImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_card_image);

        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment codes:**

```
public class free_fragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private free_recycler_adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

    private Context context;
    private boolean isDataFetched;
    private boolean mIsVisibleToUser;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_free_layout, container, false);

        context = getContext();

        if (mIsVisibleToUser) {
            LoadData();
        }

        ///----- RecyclerView -----
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdf_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new free_recycler_adapter(context, dataModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
        List<DataModel> dataModels = event.getInfoModels();
/*        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            //mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }*/
        if (event.fragmentTag.equals("forfragment1")) {
            mAdapter.add(dataModels);
            isDataFetched = true;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        mIsVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isDataFetched && getContext() != null) {
            context = getContext();
            LoadData(); //Remove this call from onCreateView
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        freeDataInfo dataInfo = new freeDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getFreeDataInfo(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

How can i show data for offline without `Sqlite DataBase`? Thanks all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every good network framework provides Response caching. So it's better to use caching instead of using mysql or shared presences to cache the Api response.

For more details how to cache response in okHttp - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097050/1741586

Just use these methods in your Util class -

```
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", String.format("max-age=%d, only-if-cached, max-stale=%d", 120, 0))
                .build();
    }
};

private static void createCacheForOkHTTP() {
    Cache cache = null;
    cache = new Cache(getDirectory(), 1024 * 1024 * 10);
    okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
}

// returns the file to store cached details
private File getDirectory() {
    return new File(“location”); 
}
```

Add interceptor to the OkHttpClient instance:

```
okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR);
```

And finally add OkHttpClient to the RestAdapter:

```
RestAdapter.setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient));
```

These whole implementation is independent of your project. You need to just put in your Uitility class and start using it :)

Comment: @Updated my answer, kindly check :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharepreference save data in /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml

Comment: can you send me true code with my above code? pleaseeeee . i really need this help