# Cache requests using retrofit2 and okhttp3

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit2 to cash responses using cache interceptor

```
 @Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(context)) {
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + MAX_AGE)
                .build();
    } else {
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + MAX_STALE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

but i need to cache specific requests not all of it, how to do that?

Comment: You have your request in `Chain`, you can check url or what you need.

Comment: Not sure. But looking at https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/making-retrofit-work-for-you-ohio-devfest-2016 you add headers to your calls and then check the same in intercept and do what is required. Check slide 37 to 43

Comment: I there away to cache specific requests Internally without override "Cache-Control" header in the request sent to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain)
```

The chain here contains the request that is being made.

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) {
    Request request = chain.request()
}
```

You can inspect this request and act on the info, for example with `request.url()` and `request.headers()`.

See more about intercepting [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Comment: Thanks @Tim really helpful.

Comment: I there away to cache specific requests Internally without override  "Cache-Control" header in the request sent to server?

Comment: @Sahar probably. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119253/retrofit-okhttp-client-how-to-cache-the-response and other examples